# Composition containing $\sin x$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f$ is differentiable for all real numbers with $f(0)=-3$, $f(1)=3$, $f(1)=3$, $f'(0)=3$ and $f'(1)=5$. Let $g(x) = \sin(\pi f(x))$. Evaluate the following expressions.
>
> a. $g'(0)$
> b. $g'(1)$

I'm completely lost, can someone give me a hint on how to approach it?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$g'(x)=(\sin (\pi f(x)))'=\cos (\pi f(x))\times \pi f'(x)$$